# how to implement search Token (like in mac Lion )in Java?

Tags: java, swing

I am thinking to implement search token (see below) in java. I have my different fields to search from and text to search. I am a little confused on how to make the UI like the rectangular ellipse and text in it and a cross button on it. How do we make that in JTextArea. Ideas are welcome.

Example of a search token:

[image: Example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this question is purely about the UI, then you need to change the [LookAndFeel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html) to something that matches Mac OS.

I don't think there is a Mac like LAF out of the box, but a quick Google search shows some promising results.

Comment: Its just for the UI. I am not sure if those are buttons are just rectangular ellipse.